# Hot Reload not working properly with some tags? (ViewCell/DataTemplate)

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2022, maui, .net-maui

I have this XAML

```
<Label Text="Logfile" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate  x:DataType="model:LogEntity">
      <ViewCell>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*" BackgroundColor="Blue">
        
          <Label Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
          <Label Text="{Binding  LogTime}" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
        
        </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If I change these tags

```
<Label Text="Logfile" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}">
```

the changes appear immediately in the app. But when I change anything within this tag

```
<ViewCell>
  <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*" BackgroundColor="Blue">
            
    <Label Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
    <Label Text="{Binding  LogTime}" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
            
  </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

nothing happens.

Are there any known limitations to this? Maybe because it's inside a DataTemplate? I haven't seen any limitation in this regards over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.3.0 Preview 1.1.

My settings in Visual Studio are:

Debugging -> .NET/C++ Hot Reload (Probably not relevant for this context)
[image]

Debugging -> XAML Hot Reload
[image]

I am debugging as Windows App on a Windows machine (Windows 10 Home, 21H2).

Under View -> Output -> Xamarin Hot Reload, when I make a change to the "Label" tag, it says:

> [12:34:18 PM]  Applying XAML Hot Reload update

When I make a change within the "ViewCell", nothing happens in the output window.

**Workaround:**
While writing this, I noticed a workaround:

- Make changes to the "ViewCell" tag
- Cut the whole "ViewCell" tag and save
- Hot Reload does apply the changes and the content disappears in the app
- Paste the "ViewCell" back with the changes and voilà!

This is certainly something I can live with for a while, but it would be great to not have to apply any workarounds for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be the ViewCell of the ListView. If you use a CollectionView and define your own template, hot reload will work as it should.

You can find an example of CollectionView at [Specify CollectionView layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout)